# C++ int via socket send(): differnent value in TCP package on Linux / MacOS

Tags: c++, linux, macos, sockets

I have a Client/Server application written in C++. The client sends a structure (proxy_header) containing three int 32. This triggers the server to send information back. Problem is that the server doesn't reply if the client runs on OS X (El Capitan). Tcpdump reveals different values of the structure sent.

The C++ code is as follows:

Initialising the message to the server:

```
struct { int m:32; int x:32; int y:32; } proxy_header;
proxy_header.m = 0x02212102;
proxy_header.x = 1;
proxy_header.y = 1;
```

...
Sending:

```
    {   int r;
if ((r = send(t->fd, (void*)&proxy_header, sizeof(proxy_header), 0)) != sizeof(proxy_header)) {
    error("Failed to send proxy header (%d != %d)", r, sizeof(proxy_header));
    goto error;
    }
```

...
Waiting for answer - recv():

```
if ((r = recv(t->fd, (void*)&(proxy_answer), sizeof(proxy_answer), MSG_WAITALL)) != sizeof(proxy_answer)) {
  printf("Failed to receive ...")
    }
else {
  printf("Successfully received...");
}
```

The program compiles and works well on Linux. On MacOS I get "Failed to receive...".

tcpdumping the packages, I discovered the following:

On **Ubuntu**, I can see a SYN/ACK, then PSH from Client to Server which responds ACK, then PSH from Server to client which responds ACK.

The first push (from client) contains this:

```
char peer0_0[] = { /* Packet 4 */
0x02, 0x21, 0x21, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

On **MacOS**, the same happens up to the first PSH from the client which is ACK by the server. The server then just sends a FIN.

This is what the push contains:

```
char peer0_0[] = {
0x02, 0x21, 0x21, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
```

Apparently it is different... Why?

Comment: What is `recv` returning when it fails? If it returns `-1`, use `perror()` to see the reason for the error.

Comment: I've used errno, apparently it doesn't fail but just does not receive anything (0 bytes).

Comment: That's EOF, which means that the client closed the connection before sending anything.

Comment: Yes, the socket shuts down orderly. On TCPDUMP I can also see the FIN package. The server just does not send data before finishing... which brought me to the question if the client sent the right init message.

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted the tcpdump. Also, do you see any difference if you do the dump on both the client and server? That would indicate packets being lost.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as a "push" segment. `PSH` is just a flag in a data segment that says that the data should be sent to the receiving application immediately, rather than being buffered in the network stack.

Comment: Ok, thx for letting me know. However there was data coming ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a problem of endianness (reversed data bytes).

Considering what you get when sending from the MAC OS client, data format seams to be "big-endian", while the server likely uses "little-endian" format. (Is the computer running MAC OS a PowerPC ?)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

One way to fix this is to use, on both sides (client & server), data buffers independant of the platform endianness. You may use, for example, boost endian_buffers:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/endian/doc/buffers.html

Your data structure may look like this:

```
struct {
    little_int32_buf_t m;
    little_int32_buf_t x;
    little_int32_buf_t y;
} proxy_header;
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but why would that cause `recv()` to return 0 bytes, rather than returning the structure with incorrect values?

Comment: Another fix is to use `htonl()` and `ntohl()` to convert the data to/from network byte order.

Comment: @BMLT: ok, then, you can follow Barmar's comment and use htonl() to populate your structure on client side, and ntohl() to get data back from structure on server side.

Comment: @MBLT Did this really solve the problem? I could understand if the problem were that the server is validating the data, but it doesn't explain why the server doesn't receive anything at all.

Comment: Let's say it provided me with an idea what to look for. The server receives a number as a signal to send data. If the number is wrong the server sends nothing but closes the connection. If the byte order is wrong, the server receives the wrong number... I had a preprocessor directive to change the order if __BYTE_ORDER was big endian. For whatever reason the Mac always ran into that, even although it is in fact little endian.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that only the gcc compiler that comes with Rtools for MacOS does this... (I was developing a lib for an r package). The compiler coming with Xcode does not.